# Can regeneration save my creatures from Turn // Burn?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I have a creature with regeneration. My opponent responds to me activating regeneration with the Turn side of [Turn // Burn](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=369080).

Can I then activate regeneration again to make it a 0/1 weird with regeneration?

Comment: When you say "with regeneration" do you mean "with an activated ability allowing it to regenerate" or "with a regeneration shield"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can activate an activated ability as often as you can pay its activation cost.

But you don't need to. The ability will still resolve even if the creature no longer has the ability when it resolves.

For example, say the creature in question is a [Dutiful Thrull](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Dutiful%20Thrull).

1. Your opponent casts [Shock](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Shock) targeting your Dutiful Thrull.
2. In response, you activate its ability.
3. In response, he casts Turn.
4. Turn resolves: The Dutiful Thrull is now a 0/1 red Weird with no abilities.
5. Dutiful Thrull's ability resolves: A regeneration shield is placed on Dutiful Thrull.
6. Shock resolves: It deals two damage to the 0/1 Dutiful Thrull.
7. SBAs are performed: The creature would be destroyed, but the regen shield kicks in. Dutiful Thrull is tapped, removed from combat and all marked damage is removed.

You could activate Dutiful Thrull's ability a second time between steps 3 and 4, which will give it a second shield for later on in the turn.

---

> 112.7a Once activated or triggered, an ability exists on the stack independently of its source. Destruction or removal of the source after that time won’t affect the ability. [...]

Comment: This way the creature has an extra regeneration shield until the end of the phase(turn?) in case they try to finish it off.

Comment: Yes, if you activate it twice, it'll have two shields, which will replace two instances of destruction.

Comment: Added an example.

Comment: The fact that you can give something extra regeneration shields "just in case" reflects some serious weirdness in the regeneration rules.

Comment: @warbaker it used to be more sensible in 4thEdition where there was a damage prevention/regeneration step after damage was assigned where those things were done before creatures were destroyed. The new rules are cleaner, but weirder.

Comment: @warbacker, How is that weird? Multiple levels of protection is a common theme in ... well just about every game with such a concept.

Comment: @ikegami Because a card doesn't say "Add a regeneration shield," it says "Regenerate." The rules translate that into adding a shield because that's the simplest way to make the mechanic work in a stack-based game, but it leads to some not-very-flavorful edge cases. Flavor-wise, regeneration is something that you do after you've been injured that causes you not to die, but it's too complicated to model it that way in Magic.

Comment: @warbaker, "Create a regeneration shield for Wolfir Avenger" is just too wordy to write on the card.

Comment: @ikegami See Nick's comment about how it was implemented in 4th Edition. Here are details: http://www.wizards.com/Magic/Magazine/Article.aspx?x=mtg/daily/feature/52b

Comment: @warbaker, (Just saw your comment now) Wow, 4th ed's definition is positively broken. "Enchant creature" enchanting cards in the graveyard? Trivially easy LTB/ETB loops for 1 mana per loop? wow. The problem have nothing to do with MTG being a stack-based game. (Which it's not. Numerous actions don't use the stack.) My earlier comments stand.

Comment: @ikegami The point in showing 4th ed's rules was to prove that the intended flavor for regeneration is that something gets mortally wounded, but then regenerates so that it doesn't die. The regeneration shield is a mechanism for cleanly converting that flavor to a stack-based system. It is indeed clean, and it usually corresponds perfectly with the flavor of regeneration, but sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: @warbaker, Actually, 4ed had it dying then coming back according to the doc you linked. The current rules is the one where "something gets mortally wounded, but then regenerates so that it doesn't die."